# Dynamically adding Spring Security tags via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my Spring-MVC application, I am using a template's JavaScript file in order to create a datatable with an "add" button. In the template's file, the button is added in the toolbar like this:

```
$("div.toolbar").html(
'<div class="table-tools-actions">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addBtn">
    Add
  </button>
 </div>');
```

For certain pages, i.e. "/users", I want this button to be available only to users with the Superadmin role and hence want to use Spring Security's security:authorize tag. I tried to do this by editing the js file like this:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("users") > -1) {
  $("div.toolbar").html(
     '<div class="table-tools-actions">
      <security:authorize access="hasRole(&#39;SUPERADMIN&#39;)">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addBtn">
          Add
        </button>
      </security:authorize>
      </div>');
} else {
  $("div.toolbar").html(
   '<div class="table-tools-actions">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addBtn">
        Add
      </button>
    </div>');
  }
```

But the security tags are not taken into account and are simply visible when viewing the source code.

[Element inspection in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eowZE.png)

Note that security works fine when put in the jsp file around static components. I guess that this has to do with the lifecycle, since the security constraints must be applied before the page is fully rendered. Is there any workaround for this? Thanks!

Comment: But you're not using spring, you're using javascript, of course, the code is going to be visible through the inspector...

Comment: @winter Yes, I understand that it makes sense that the tags are added at a later point in the lifecycle and thus not being taken into account by Spring. I could bypass this if I put the whole static html code in my jsp and not use the template files, but I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically put spring tags in a page, if not from javascript resources, maybe from the controller.

Comment: the short answer is no because, the javascript code is only interpreted by the navigator, but is always visible. In this case, you must define that on the server side, in other words in a `JSP`, because it concerns the security of the application.